# Sprite jump from position(x, y) to position(width-x, y) in a parabolic way

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm working on Cocos2D, and I need to make the sprite jump from `position(x, y)` to `position(width-x, y)` in a parabolic way. It's my first time working in game development.

How can I make the animation of jumping from one side to the other side?

My current piece of code while screen is tapped

```
- (void)ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGSize screenSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    if(!self.anim.flipY){
        self.anim.position = ccp(screenSize.width - self.anim.position.x, self.anim.position.y);
        self.anim.flipY = true;
    }
    else{
        self.anim.position = ccp(screenSize.width - self.anim.position.x, self.anim.position.y);
        self.anim.flipY = false;
    }

}
```

I read on a forum, that it requires to use gravity and velocity? Any hint? I barely have an idea!

Comment: In this case, You have to use high school maths, You have to find the points on the parabolic path. For that you have to consider basic of parabola. http://216.253.94.53/Algebra/Graphing/Basics/basics.html check this link for basic.
If you don't get the way, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you need, but you can make a sprite jump using actions.

```
// Create a CCJumpTo action.
CCJumpTo *jumpAction = [CCJumpTo actionWithDuration:2.0 position:ccp(100,100) height:50 jumps:1];
// Tell your sprite to run our action.
[mySprite runAction:jumpAction];
```

There's also `CCJumpBy`.

They have a parabolic style. Play around with the `height` argument.

Comment: I don't think , Either CCJumpTo or CCJumpBy will give parabolic path.

Comment: Actually , this will always give x=y^2 parabolic path.If you want x = -y^2 or y = x^2 or y = -x^2 than you will not get that by this...Will we get other parabolic path?